# multiplication of 2-dimensional array java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, multiplication

I want to enter 2 dimensional arrays by joptionpane and display the multiplication of it  by java, 
 I tried do this but I don't no why the result always is (0 0 0),I think that the result arrays is empty! could anyone help me ....!!??

```
    System.out.print("can not multiply");
}
 public static double[][] multiplyMatrix(double[][] x, double[][] z) {
double[][] result = new double[x.length][z[0].length];    
for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
  for ( int j = 0; j <z[0].length; j++){
  result[i][j]=0;
  for (int k = 0; k < z.length; k++)
    result[i][j] += x[i][k] * z[k][j];}

return result;
```

}

Comment: This code actually hurts my eyes to read, the indentation is atrocious.

Comment: i am just a beginner in java ,
and am asked to make this program by my few knowledge!

Comment: There are quite a few syntax errors in your code. Currently, your code will not compile. For example, `double[][] result = new double[z.length][z][0].length];` and `for (int column = 0; column <h\[row\].length ; column++) {
`. I'd start by correcting those.

Comment: thanks @gonzo
i think that is some wrong in copying code from netbeans
my program run out but with 0`s result

Comment: @Abeersz Yeah I figured it was something like that. Can you edit the question with the correct code then? With correct syntax.

Comment: @gonzo   I edited it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You populate your `A` array in both of your `for` loops. You have to populate `B` in the second for loop.

```
double[][] B = new double[n2][m2];
int k;
int l;
for (k = 0; k < n2; k++) {
    for (l = 0; l < m2; l++) {
        String s1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter B" + "[" + (k) + (l) + "]" + " element ");
        //A[k][l] = Integer.parseInt(s1);  //This should be populating B
        B[k][l] = Integer.parseInt(s1);    //Change it to this
    }
}
```

After fixing that issue, you still have some bugs in your multiplication method. But now that you actually get a `result` array, you can debug it pretty easily.

Hope this helps.

Comment: oh i didn't noticed that! all thanks for you ,the programme run out with true result.
could you till me what is the bugs that you mean in the multiplication methods?

Comment: @Abeersz: Populating `A` twice has been a typical copy-and-paste error. Factor out a method instead. (Telling you bugs wont go any distance enabling you to find upcoming ones.)